# Save/output dynamically generated html source using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search form that can be built dynamically by the user using code such as:

`$('tr.form_row:last').clone(true).insertAfter('tr.form_row:last');`

All of this is working fine, however, I would like to save the dynamically generated form html when the form is submitted.  I have tried using `$(#my_form').html()` but this doesn't appear to have the dynamic content, instead, it's just the default html before customisation that is gathered.

Is there a way of getting the generated source using javascript/jquery?  It would need to include the value within the input fields that the user has typed etc.

**EDIT** - I've included my coding so far:

This is the coding I have tried - it uses jquery form plugin and I populate a hidden form field called 'search_html':

```
var search_form = {
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        var search_html = '<table>';
        $('.form_row').each(function() {
            search_html += $(this).html();
        });
        search_html += '</table>';
        $("#search_html").val(search_html);
    },
    success: function(html) { 
        $('#search_output').html(html);
    } 
};  
$('#search_form').ajaxForm(search_form);
```

When I submit the form, HTML is passed within the hidden 'search_html' field, but it is only the first table row and doesn't have the values of the input fields populated.

Comment: can you post the code from your attempt?

Comment: Something like this might work: http://jsfiddle.net/fhbjZ/

Comment: @darshanags - now edited post to include my attempt - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to this not appearing to be possible in the way I had hoped/thought, I instead wrote coding in PHP to collect and store the generated form details in a database.  Then when the user comes back to the form, I check to see if their user_id is in the search history table and if so, use PHP to build the form back to the way they had it.

Code when form is submitted:

```
foreach($_POST["where_field"] as $key => $val){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO dynamic_form (user_id, where_field, where_value, where_criteria) VALUES (:var1, :var2, :var3, :var4)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':var1', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var2', $_POST["where_field"][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var3', $_POST["where_value"][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var4', $_POST["where_criteria"][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Then on the actual form page, query the database for `$user_id` and loop through the results to build the form as they had it.